# Stability of the Lienard Equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions

Consider the Lienard Equation
\begin{equation*}
x'' + g(x)x' + h(x) =0 .
\end{equation*}
We can rewrite this and gain the system
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
x'\\y'
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
y\\
-g(x)y-h(x)
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
In the book of Walter about Ordinary differential equations he states, that for $xh(x)>0$ and $g(x)\geq 0$ for $x\neq 0$, the solution $(x,y)^T\equiv (0,0)^T$ of our system is asymptotically stable iff we can find a sequence $(x_k)_k\subset \mathbb{R}$ with $x_k\to 0$ and $g(x_k)>0$.

For sure the solution is asymptotically stable if we have $g(x)>0$ for $x\neq 0$, because we can choose a Lyapunov-Function
\begin{equation*}
V(x,y)= \frac{1}{2}y^2 + H(x)
\end{equation*}
were $H(x)= \int_0^x h(s)\, ds$. Then $\dot{V}(x,y)=-y^2g(x)$ and the only invariant set of $N=\{ \dot{V} = 0 \}=\{xy=0\}$ is $\{(0,0) \}$ so we can apply well known theorems to conclude the proof. But I don't see how we can proof this similary if we don't have $g(x)>0$ in some pointet neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

Any hints would be helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does the answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480866/stability-in-a-li%c3%a9nard-system give you sufficient insights?

Comment: If I knew there are two sequences $x_k \searrow 0$ and $y_k \nearrow 0$ with $g(x_k),g(y_k)>0$, I could argue that $h(x) \int_0^x g(t) \, dt >0$ for $x\neq 0$ and I could use a similar Lyapunov-Function to solve my problem. Wihout, I'm not sure if I can find an argument to fix this.